# Error: Typescript found the following errors: Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular 2 app generated using angular cli. I am using typescript. It fails when I import redux-logger using:`const createLogger = require('redux-logger');`

The error is:

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
/Users/abdul.badru/2016/Development/BudgetSoftware/app/budgetapp/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-eQlgH862.tmp/0/src/app/app.module.ts (24, 22): Cannot find name 'require'.
/Users/abdul.badru/2016/Development/BudgetSoftware/app/budgetapp/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-eQlgH862.tmp/0/src/app/store/index.ts (5, 22): Cannot find name 'require'.
```

What is going on here? What I am missing?

Comment: `import createLogger from "redux-logger"`?

Comment: I have tried, but when I do that now it says: `Cannot find module 'redux-logger'.`

Comment: Try `npm install --save redux-logger` and see if it works.

Comment: I already did npm install but I have done it again. Typescript is still giving  me the same error: `Cannot find module 'redux-logger'`. But when I put `const createLogger = require('redux-logger');` and point the cursor over `require` it says `Corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json`

Comment: Hi Abdul. Did you specifically run `npm install --save redux-logger` or did you only run `npm install`?

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I did both but not working. Here is the result of my npm install --save redux-logger: `badrumacbookpro:budgetapp abdul.badru$ npm install --save redux-logger
budget-app@0.0.0 /Users/abdul.badru/2016/Development/BudgetSoftware/app/budgetapp
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@0.3.0
└── redux-logger@2.6.1 
`

Comment: The package is already installed and it also appear on my package.json as: `"redux-logger": "^2.6.1",` I don't know why is not finding the module.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add on typings.d.ts file the following declaration:

```
declare var require: any;
```

And now I can require:

```
const createLogger = require('redux-logger');
```

Comment: I put this declaration atop the require and all worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Require is a global namespace and it isn't properly defined. You can install it's definition file with [the typings installer](https://github.com/typings/typings), if you're using that:

```
typings install --global --save-dev dt~require
```

Or you could add the typing file manually. The file can [be found here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/requirejs).

Or you can tell the Typescript compilier that require exists and can be anything by putting the following in your file or your global .d.ts file (index.d.ts, typings.d.ts):

```
declare var require: any;
```